# Confusion Matrix-Sklearn 0.22 Numbers format error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to use plot_confusion_matrix from sklearn 0.22

But my numbers are in format 1.3e+0.2

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 230))
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X, y, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.xlabel('True label')
plt.ylabel('Predicted label')
```

[image: confusion matrix figure]

How can i fix this?

Comment: instead of a image of code, a code snippet is better with some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value format argument in the function. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

Here is an example of using values_format arguement :

```
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(classifier, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=class_names,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize=normalize,
                                   values_format="d")
```

if you want to show a float with only you can use the following format '.1f'. It's the same values_format used in seaborn.

Comment: Please, provide an example of how should value_format parameter be used. I will upvote your answer then :)